# Can't refactor code in a do block, IO return type doesn't match

Tags: haskell

This was the original code

```
putBoard :: Board -> IO ()
putBoard [a,b,c,d,e] = do putRow 1 a
                          putRow 2 b
                          putRow 3 c
                          putRow 4 d
                          putRow 5 e
```

I wanted to rewrite it as

```
putBoard :: Board -> IO ()
putBoard b = do [putRow r v | (r,v) <- zip [1..] b]
                return ()
```

but I get

```
    * Couldn't match type `[]' with `IO'
      Expected type: IO (IO ())
        Actual type: [IO ()]
    * In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        [putRow r v | (r, v) <- zip [1..] b]
      In the expression:
        do [putRow r v | (r, v) <- zip [1..] b]
           return ()
      In an equation for `putBoard':
          putBoard b
            = do [putRow r v | (r, v) <- zip [1..] b]
                 return ()
   |
35 | putBoard b = do [putRow r v | (r,v) <- zip [1..] b]
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Why is the "return ()" ignored?

Comment: acquaint yourself with [do notation](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/do-notation/info).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you here construct is a *list* of `IO ()` actions, but a list of `IO ()` actions is not an `IO ()` object that will perform all these actions.

You can work with [**`sequence_ :: (Foldable t, Monad m) => t (m a) -> m ()`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:sequence_) to perform the actions in a list (actually any `Foldable`) of monadic objects:

```
putBoard :: Board -> IO ()
putBoard b = sequence_ (zipWith putRow [1..] b)
```

or slightly shorter:

```
putBoard :: Board -> IO ()
putBoard = sequence_ . zipWith putRow [1..]
```

We can also work with [**`zipWithM_ :: Applicative m => (a -> b -> m c) -> [a] -> [b] -> m ()`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:zipWithM_) which does the zipping from two lists:

```
import Control.Monad(zipWithM_)

putBoard :: Board -> IO ()
putBoard = zipWithM_ putRow [1..]
```

Comment: That's great. 

I feel I am still thinking imperatively where I execute a series of statements and used return () to try an satisfy the type signature.
Why didn't "return ()" satisfy the type signature?

Comment: @PHemans: because it expects that each line in the `do` has type `IO a` (where `a` can be any type), but a list is not an `IO`.

Comment: That makes sense, "do" is syntactic sugar right? thank you.

Comment: @PHemans: yes `do {x <- a; b}` is equivalent to `a >>= \x -> b`